# Getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@uidu/ckeditor5-tokenizr' when importing npm package that I installed

Tags: vue.js, npm, ckeditor5

So I installed @uidu/ckeditor5-tokenizr to my project. I see it in node_modules/@uidu/ckeditor5-tokenizr but when I have
`import tokenizr from '@uidu/ckeditor5-tokenizr';`

in my Vue Components  section I get the following error

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@uidu/ckeditor5-tokenizr' in <path to file here>`

I'm not doing anything crazy here.

Here is the file

```
<template>
  <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
</template>


<script>
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import tokenizr from '@uidu/ckeditor5-tokenizr';

export default {
  name: "Editor",
  components: {
    ckeditor: CKEditor.component
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorData: '<p>Editor Text Here</p>',
      editorConfig: {
      }
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was changing the import to

```
import Tokenizr from '@uidu/ckeditor5-tokenizr/src/tokenizr';
```

The full path name. I still don't know why this was an issue because in the package.json within @uidu/ckeditor5-tokenizr there was this defined

`"main": "src/tokenizr.js",`

which I'm pretty sure should have found what I manually entered. Either way this fixed my issue for now.